# typeahead.js search box navigation with enter key

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js

I'm trying to implement a search box with typeahead.js where the user can navigate to entries by clicking on line items in typeahead or using keyboard up and down to select entry and navigate to them by enter key.

This is my html

```
<div id="remote">
  <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Search for people"> 
</div>
```

This is my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var castDirectors = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  prefetch: '../api/v1/search/people_typeahead',
  remote: '../api/v1/search/people_typeahead?q=%QUERY',
    dupDetector: function(remoteMatch, localMatch) {
        return remoteMatch.value === localMatch.value;
    }
});

castDirectors.initialize();

$('#remote .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
  name: 'cast-directors',
  displayKey: 'value',
  source: castDirectors.ttAdapter(),
    templates: {
        empty: [
      '<div class="empty-message">',
      'no matching names',
      '</div>'
    ].join('\n'),
        suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<p><a id="typeahead" href="{{link}}">{{value}}</a></p>')
    }       
});
});
```

With the input type="text", if I navigate with keyboard and select with enter key, it just fills the textbox. I'd like the enter key to equate to clicking on the line item. What do I need to change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managed to add the following to my javascript and it worked nicely

```
$('#remote .typeahead').on('typeahead:selected', function (e, datum) {
    window.location.href = datum.link
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't put a href inside your items. But inside your typeahead use select function like below:

```
 select: function( event, key ) {
            window.location.href ="Your-Key-related-url-here";
        }
```

Its working for me. Let me know for any further issue.

Comment: Sorry I'm kinda new to javascript and don't know how I can add this line in my code. Can you be more specific in what code I need to edit in order for this to work Shailesh? Thanks!